# AndEngine:why those sprites get distorted?

Tags: android, andengine

[image]

I am facing 2 problems.

Questions are listed in picture above.

And main code snippets like this:
My device has a 1024x600 resolution.

Engine:

```
    this.mCamera = new Camera(0, 0,*device'width*,*device'height*);     
final EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true,     ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new FillResolutionPolicy(), this.mCamera);
    engineOptions.getTouchOptions().setNeedsMultiTouch(true);
```

Background:

```
BitmapTextureAtlas bta = new BitmapTextureAtlas(mGame.getTextureManager(),WIDTH_SCENE_PNG,HEIGHT_SCENE_PNG, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
ITextureRegion it = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromResource(bta, mGame, R.drawable.bg_main, 0, 0);
bta.load();
final Sprite sprite = new Sprite(0, 0,*device'width*,*device'height*,it, mGame.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
SpriteBackground bg = new SpriteBackground(sprite);
bg.setColor(Color.PINK);
setBackground(bg);
```

Sprites:

```
    BitmapTextureAtlas btaTools = new BitmapTextureAtlas(mGame.getTextureManager(), 30, 40);
ITextureRegion itDelete = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromResource(btaTools, c, R.drawable.sprite_delete,0,0);
    btaTools.load();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem.

The point is that I moved my resources(png images) from project's drawable-hdpi folder to drawable foler, sprites look nice then.

raw or asset folders are also OK.
 Your answer is also helpful for me.Thank you! @Christoph

Answer (score 0):

**The distortions** could come from the `TextureOptions`. For the `TextureAtlas` of your background sprite you use the `TextureOptions.BILINEAR`. The `TextureAtlas` of your tools however don't use any options. I guess they have *transparent* areas? When you use transparent sprites try `TextureOptions.NEAREST_PREMULTIPLYALPHA` or `TextureOptions.BLINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA`. I for one use `TextureOptions.NEAREST` and it works fine for me (even with transparency). Try out some of the options maybe the distortions go away.

**The size of your background**: for the `TextureAtlas bta` you already use those constants `WIDTH_SCENE_PNG` and `HEIGHT_SCENE_PNG`, why don't you use them for the size of you sprite as well? Anyway, my guess is, that your camera has a different size. For a fullscreen image try:

```
final Sprite sprite = new Sprite(0, 0,mEngine.getCamera().getWidth(),mEngine.getCamera().getHeight(),it, mGame.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
```

- Christoph

Comment: I fixed my problem.The point is that I moved my resources(png images) from project's drawable-hdpi folder to drawable foler, sprites look nice then.raw or asset folder are also OK.              Your answer is also helpful for me.Thank you! @Christoph